# ¿Qué falla en mi código?

Tags: python

Estaba probando diferentes funciones en Python, y he llegado a crear un comparador muy básico de coches.

(Aclaro cochePrecio1 y cochePrecio2 es como si fuera coche1 y coche2, las puse por poner)

```
def marcas():

    cocheMarca = input("Marca: ")
    cochePrecio = int(input("Precio: "))
    cocheKM = int(input("KM: "))
    cocheAnyo = int(input("Anyo: "))

    return cocheMarca, cochePrecio, cocheKM, cocheAnyo

def precioMayor(cochePrecio1, cochePrecio2):
    if cochePrecio1[1] > cochePrecio2[1]:
        print(cochePrecio1[0], "es mas caro")
    elif cochePrecio2[1] > cochePrecio1[1]:
        print(cochePrecio2[0], "es mas caro")
    else:
        print("Los dos cuestan lo mismo")

def masKM(cochePrecio1, cochePrecio2):
    if cochePrecio1[1] > cochePrecio2[1]:
        print(cochePrecio1[0], "esta mas usado")
    elif cochePrecio2[1] > cochePrecio1[1]:
        print(cochePrecio2[0], "esta mas usado")
    elif cochePrecio2[1] == cochePrecio1[1]:
        print("Los dos tienen los mismos KM")

def masAnyo(cochePrecio1, cochePrecio2):
    if cochePrecio1[1] > cochePrecio2[1]:
        print(cochePrecio1[0], "tiene mas anyos")
    elif cochePrecio2[1] > cochePrecio1[1]:
        print(cochePrecio2[0], "tiene mas anyos")
    else:
        print("Tienen los mismos anyos")

cochePrecio1 = marcas()
cochePrecio2 = marcas()

precioMayor(cochePrecio1, cochePrecio2)
masKM(cochePrecio1, cochePrecio2)
masAnyo(cochePrecio1, cochePrecio2)
```

El problema está en que si precio2 es mayor que precio1 en cualquier cosa, ya sea sólo Precio o KM todo se cambia a mayor a favor de Precio2, por lo cuál precio2 será mayor en todo aunque realmente no lo sea.

¿Alguien me podría explicar el por qué pasa esto?

Comment: Estas comparando siempre por el mismo indice, o sea, por el mismo concepto. Para comparar KMS, en lugar de usar `cochePrecio1[1]`, usa `cochePrecio1[2]`. La variable `cochePrecio1`, es una tupla, y los KMS están en la tercera posición dentro de la tupla

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! @CandidMoe